How to set up new menu as my homepage?
I created a joomla! 4 website and I wanted to use the main menu to create my homepage but then on all 404 error pages were my main menu modules. So my 404 error pages were displayed in my homepage.
It was very ugly.
So I created a new menu named Homepage and reassigned all my "homepage" modules to this menu.
But how to make this Homepage menu my default homepage?
When I enter mywebsite.com I am redirected to the Main menu (I mean Joomla "Main menu") which is now blank.
I am required to go to mywebsite.com/homepage to go to my homepage >_<
How to solve this?
Thank you

Home/default menu item can be set by clicking Set as Home button in menu item list or checking Default Page field in menu item form. But this will not solve your problem. 404 pages resolve to the default/home menu item. Error pages will simply start showing modules from Homepage menu item. You need a plugin to change this behavior. Another option is to customize the error.php layout of your template to remove unwanted module positions from error pages.

Are you sure I must install a plugin to avoid something that looks like a standard functionality?

This is the standard behavior at the moment. You could try opening a feature request on the issue tracker https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues.

Make sure you click and choose on the menu you selected and click as default. You will notice the default because there is a yellow star icon.
